# How to use cxFreeze to convert a Python program to a Windows executable?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I would like to preface this by saying that I basically don't know how computers work.

I need to convert a Python program (untitled.py) to an exe and I'm using cxFreeze. I used the installer and the [tutorial](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html#script) for cxFreeze told me to run

```
cxfreeze untitled.py --target-dir dist
```

So I go into Git Bash and type

```
cd /c/python27/scripts
./cxfreeze untitled.py --target-dir dist
```

And then Bash tells me that

```
bash: ./cxfreeze: c:\python\32-bit\2.7\python.exe^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong? I am using Win 7 and Python 2.7.

Comment: can you try it in a windows shell instead of git bash? the `^M` is making me think CRLF vs LF endings might be screwing things up

Comment: `c:\python\32-bit\2.7\python.exe` is not going to work in a Unix environment

Comment: @cricket_007 right but Git Bash does some black magic. You can see he's actually running `/c/python27/scripts/cxfreeze` which is symlinked back to the `C:\python\32-bit\...` in the windows environment.

Comment: @AdamSmith Sure. I suppose the real question is why Git bash being used

Comment: @cricket_007 "I basically don't know how computers work." I read that as "I'm following tutorials and learning good practices like version control, which has lead me to use Git Bash." I see this as a step in the right direction, even if it's obfuscating (or even causing) an error here!!! :)

Comment: @cricket_007 system admin disabled CMD.

Comment: @Pavel you're out of luck then. You need to be able to drop to a shell one way or another.

Comment: You can't just run `cmd.exe` from Bash?

Comment: @AdamSmith You were right, running it in PowerShell made it work, better. Now to find where it actually stuck the .exe it made. Thanks! Command prompt-disabled. Powershell- just fine.

Comment: You have a system admin who disabled cmd and didn't disable powershell? Where the heck are you....

Comment: @AdamSmith A school with a very stupid IT.

Comment: @Pavel probably better to ask permission if you're a student at a school. Consider that circumventing security concerns in order to compile an executable is pretty much certainly an expulsion if that executable causes any (intentional or unintentional) damage. Strongly recommend you do your hacking on your own computer, or bring a laptop in.

Comment: @AdamSmith That might be smart. Thanks anyway!